# A sequence which is not comparable to polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

I am searching for an explicit example of a sequence of real numbers $(u_n)$ that satisfies the following
properties:

(1) for any $\alpha>0$, $n^{\alpha}\notin \mathcal{O}(u_n)$,

(2) There exists $\beta>0$ such that $u_n \notin \mathcal{O}(n^\beta)$.

(3) [Edited after comments] $(u_n)$ is non-decreasing

It might be easy, but I didn't find any of such $(u_n)$. 
For instance $\log(n)$ satisfies (1,3) but not (2). 
Could it be that (1,3) implies not (2) ?

Thanks

Comment: Just mix a sequence like $(\log n)$ with a sequence like $(n!)$ to get what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't see how that would give the desired behaviour, and what do you mean by mixing ?

Comment: Bounce back and forth from fast to slow: odd $n$ fast, even $n$ slow.

Comment: If you're careful you can even make it monotone.

Comment: @Yuval: How?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Ok I see now, thanks ! But what if I want $(u_n)$ to be non-decreasing ? (Question edited)

Comment: $u_1 = 1$, then $u_2 = 2!$, then $u_{k+1} =  (1 + 1/k^2) u_k$ until $u_k \le \log k$, then $u_{k+1} = (k+1)!$, etc.

Comment: For non-decreasing, slow many times, huge jump, slow many times, huge jump, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

For an explicit expression, try
$$
u_n=2^{2^{2^{\lfloor\log_2\log_2\log_2 n\rfloor+1/2}}}
$$
(valid for $n\ge4$). For positive integer $a$, if $n=2^{2^{2^a}}$ then $u_n=2^{2^{2^a\sqrt2}}=n^{2^{2^a(\sqrt2-1)}}$, which is faster than $n^\alpha$, any $\alpha > 0$. Also, $u_{n-1}=2^{2^{2^a/\sqrt2}}=n^{2^{-2^a(1-1/\sqrt{2})}}$, which is much slower than $n^\alpha$.

**Note**: This is just an explicit realization of André's suggestion of slow many times, huge jump, etc.